# Using mocks to reduce the number of tests around a method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

I would like to have some insights on the different options to test a class which has the responsibility to create a `Sample` object given two other objects.

The API for my object is the following:

```
public interface ISampleCreator
{
    Sample CreateSample(Order order, SampleService sampleService);
}
```

The logic in this method can be separated in three parts:

1. Initialize some simple properties for the `Sample` (depends on the `Order` and the `SampleService`).
2. Set a new unique name for the `Sample` (depends on the `Order.Samples` and on the `SampleService`).
3. Set some additional fields for the `Sample` (depends on the `SampleService`).

My problem is that if I want to test the method thoroughly, I have a lot of different cases to take into account with some complicated setup.

My first idea is to extract a class to generate the unique name for point 2- and extract a class to generate the additional fields for the sample.

I can then test those two classes independently and I can mock them to have fewer tests for the `CreateSample` method. For example:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void CreateSampleTest()
    {
        Order order = new Order();
        SampleService sampleService = new SampleService();
        Mock<ISampleNameGenerator> mockNameGenerator = new Mock<ISampleNameGenerator>();
        mockNameGenerator.Setup(x => x.GenerateSampleName(order.Samples, sampleService))
                         .Returns("Generated name");
        Mock<ISampleFieldsCreator> mockFieldsCreator = new Mock<ISampleFieldsCreator>();
        List<SampleField> sampleFields = new List<SampleField>();
        mockFieldsCreator.Setup(x => x.CreateFieldsForNewSample(sampleService))
                         .Returns(sampleFields);

        SampleCreator sampleCreator = new SampleCreator(mockNameGenerator.Object, mockFieldsCreator.Object);

        Sample sample = sampleCreator.CreateSample(order, sampleService);

        Assert.AreEqual("Generated name", sample.Name);
        Assert.AreEqual(sampleFields, sample.Fields);
        Assert.AreEqual(order, sample.Order);
        Assert.AreEqual(sampleService, sample.SampleService);
    }
```

The problem I have with this approach is that I am mocking classes that I own and which doesn't access any external resources: basically, I am doing mock based testing as a way to simplify the setup for my tests.

What do you think of this approach?

Can you suggest other alternatives and why you would do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The problem I have with this approach is that I am mocking classes that I own and which doesn't access any external resources: basically, I am doing mock based testing as a way to simplify the setup for my tests.

The assumption that you should only mock stuff that acceses external resources is wrong. You mock *dependencies*, whatever they are. The point of mocking is to isolate actual class/method logic from *operation details* of other components (*dependencies*).

Take a look on refactoring you introduced - extracting **unique name generation** to separate class. This sounds reasonable as the process might involve whole new set of restrictions and *inner knowledge* which your original **object  building** method doesn't need to possess.

Decoupling your code is often good idea as it leads to more single-task oriented classes, easier testing, easier objects composition, more code reuse. Unit testing often helps to spot such improvement areas exactly in a way you discovered it - making test difficult/too complex to write in first place.

Long story short - your approach is correct.

Comment: The point of mocking is indeed to isolate part of the code from other parts. This should be used sparingly though as code is rarely designed to work meaningfully in isolation. By over-isolating parts of the code, you end up artificially testing that part and thus insufficiently testing it.

Comment: @DavidArno: but unit testing deals with the lowest level of your code design and benefits from such isolation. Also I don't agree on *"should be used sparingly"* - I'd say use it (decoupling) whenever required, as it often depends on domain/project complexity, team composition, dev. process and what not. It's *"a balancing act"*.

Answer (score 1):

Unit testing is always a balancing act. Obviously, you want to test CreateSample() works as intended. As it interacts with Order and SampleService, then ideally you're tests would use instances of those objects in the tests. However, as you point out, that complicates the setup of the tests, which both creates extra work and discourages thorough testing.

One point to note about how you have structured you code is that Order and SampleService are concrete classes; you have coupled CreateSample() to those classes. If you have CreateSample() work with IOrder and ISampleService, you'll decouple the method from those other classes and thus the setup of tests will likely be easier.

Mocking your objects is a compromise. It can simplify testing, however, you have to be aware that your tests are not then testing your system, but a partial mock of your system. At times, this can help. It can also lead to a false sense of security though. You can end up testing all the parts, only to have the whole thing fall apart when you join those parts together.

Comment: In my example, Order and SampleService are POCO without any behavior: they are just bags of data. I'm not sure adding an interface for those classes would simplify the setup. It seems to me that at some point, we cannot avoid the coupling between CreateSample(), Order and SampleService.